# getting data from a database using Gulp

Tags: javascript, mysqli, pdo, gulp

I have a template and the required CSS to generate a web page using Gulp JS.

I also have a database where I store all the descriptions, pictures, dates, prices of itineraries that go into building up the page. It was originally planned to use PHP to call in page specific information and fill up the editable regions of the template and display it to the user/consumer of the data.

Can I use Gulp as a task runner to furnish the required information instead of PHP? If yes, HOW can I go about it - access the DB and get the required info?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: Gulp is a Task Runner, look at it as a development tool similar to a build system.

It is not recommended to use Gulp as a production tool. You can but it is definitely not recommended. There are deprecated packages used in Gulp v3 which cannot be updated because of breaking API changes, some of them make Gulp v3 vulnerable for attacks. This will be fixed with Gulp v4 which is around the corner, but it is not here yet.

In the end, Gulp is plain javascript. That means you can easily use one of the many sql libraries available for node.

[mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql)

My advice: Use the Webserver of your choice to generate Data. Catch the Request and generate an SQL call, then pass it to a template. That should be the easiest way of displaying data.

[guide for express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html)

Comment: Hello Ahnzh, Thank you very much for your input. I suppose it will be best to continue with PHP. You're right,  It wouldn't be really suitable to use in the production environment, even if it is version 4. PHP/PDO might be rather more stable and secure. Version 4 is around the corner since more than a year. I might fiddle around with it in the development side, when it does alas show up. Bit